# Why is "{} == false" incorrect javascript syntax , while "false == {}" is not ?

Tags: javascript

Here is the result from browser console (both firefox and chrome ) , 
`false == {}` works,but `{} == false` gives syntax error.

```
>> false == []
true
>> false == {}
false
>> 0 == false
true
>> false == []
true
>> false == {}
false
>> [] == false
true
>> {} == false
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the former case, it's not clear to the parser that `{}` represents a value.

The following works:

```
var a = {};
a == false      // false
```

Or alternatively you can use:

```
({}) == false   // false
```

So this isn't anything specific to value comparison -- rather, it's the way the code is parsed.

Nice question!

Answer (score 3):

If you run just `{}`,  you see that it's not being parsed as an object at all - it gives `undefined`! Clearly, it's being parsed as a code block. Hence, `{} == false` is a syntax error, as there is nothing on the left side of the `==`.

`{}variableName` is also not a syntax error for the same reason - it's an empty code block.

If you wrap it in parentheses, it is correctly parsed as an object literal, and works.

```
({}) == false
```

Answer (score 0):

Even this works,

```
 /{}/ == false;   // false
```

Comment: How did you answer AFTER it was closed as a duplicate??

Comment: I didnt See , after posting only,I saw it as duplicate . Sorry

Comment: I mean, technically, how did it let you?

Comment: @Scimonster smells BUGGY  !

Comment: @Scimonster: the limitation that prevents posting is only enforced on the client. If you loaded the page before it was closed and for some reason the JavaScript did not load or is not working properly, the user would be able to post after it was closed. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed